# how to make installer (exe) file in windows

Tags: wpf, windows, windows-installer

I have created a WPF application. I want to make installer file (exe) for this application.

This application also uses some other 3rd party files (bat files); which i have zipped.
I want to unzip this file while installing and set the path of unzipped dir in Path variable also.

I got a link http://www.msdotnet.co.in/2012/06/how-to-create-setup-fileexe-file-from.html#.U3GT7YGSzxp
which tells how to create a installer file.

How to achieve unzipped part and setting environment vairable while making installer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [wix from Microsoft.](http://wixtoolset.org/)

It can be run standalone, but is great run from within visual studio. You write a small xml file detailing what you want installed, and it does the rest.

To run a zip command, use a [CustomAction](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/authoring_custom_actions.html).

Comment: Docs are poor and I have folder and it's not Visual Studio. I can't find how to actually create an installer from a folder. Should be as simple as `wix CreateInstaller "C:\PathToFolder"` or even just dropping a folder on top of the executable. But it's not and there is no adequate docs. There's command-line interface: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/wixexe/ but no explanation on what to actually do to create an installer.

Comment: @KulaGGin looks like Wix v4 is new, and they're still doing stuff with it. [Try the v3 docs](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/howtos/) or ask on the wix discussions page on github.

Answer (score 1):

Search for ***Install-shield***. It is old tool but having good scripting capability like what you are expecting (i.e) Unzipping the folder and dealing with path environment variable

Answer (score 0):

Use **Inno Setup** (http://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) or **NSIS** (http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).

Both are free (open source) installation systems with many possibilities and huge community around (even here on SO).

They are really easy to use (especially Inno) and they are powerful so it is easy to achieve your required functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **Stall**:

https://github.com/jamesqo/Stall

It's an OSS project that lets you install your app from the command line, no configuration required.

**Example Usage:**

```
stall path/to/YourApp -e YourApp.exe -i YourApp.exe
```

This installs your app straight to the user's computer without having to make an intermediary MSI.

If you have to unzip files as well, you may want to just consider a simple batch files that downloads the binaries + unzips the contents + runs Stall.

Comment: This applies to your multiple similar answers: Just linking to your own library (or utility) is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code using it to do so and disclaiming makes for a better answer. See: [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/)

Comment: @Mogsdad Sorry, I'll edit it right away to explain. Thanks for the heads-up.